# Go to next visible cell using offset

Tags: excel, macros, offset, autofilter, vba

I have an autofiltered table in excel. I have to copy paste values based on certain conditions and I have to perform this on all visible cells in a particular column. I have written the code and it works well but the only thing is that it takes a lot of time as there are many rows. Can anyone please help me how to thrash time required? Here's the code. Thanks!

```
Sub TrialAnotherOne()


Windows("Epson Itemcodes.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A" & i).Select
    Selection.Copy

Windows("Epson ASINs.xlsx").Activate
    Range("U1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(0, -12).Select


If ActiveCell.Value <> "Itemcode" Then

If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Else

    If ActiveCell.Value = Workbooks("Epson Itemcodes.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value Then
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Else
    ActiveCell.Value = "Conflct"

    End If
    End If

Else
Windows("Epson Itemcodes.xlsm").Activate
Range("I" & i).Value = "No match found"

End If

If ActiveCell.Value <> "Itemcode" Then


With ActiveSheet
Do

ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Activate
Do While ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Activate
Loop

If ActiveCell.Value <> "Itemcode" Then

If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Else

    If ActiveCell.Value = Workbooks("Epson Itemcodes.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value Then
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Else

    ActiveCell.Value = "Conflct"

    End If
    End If

Else
Exit Do

End If

Loop
End With

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You should watch this video series:[Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).  This one is a must:[Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&t=3082s)

Comment: you should move your question to code review, here is the link: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Range Copy, Cut, and Delete automatically selects only the visible cells of a filtered range.

[image]

```
Sub CopyFilteredColumn()
    Dim Target As Range

    'Size the Target range to fit the table
    'Define the starting row "C1:J19"
    'Extend the Target range to the last row .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    'Column C is used because it will never have blank cells
    With Worksheets("Source Sheet")
        Set Target = .Range("C1:J19", .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    Target.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">40", Operator:=xlAnd

    'Header and data
    'Copy the visible cells of the 3rd column of the table
    Target.Columns(3).Copy Worksheets("Target Sheet").Range("A1")
    'Data only - Includes 1 blank cell at the end
    Target.Offset(1).Columns(3).Copy Worksheets("Target Sheet").Range("C1")

End Sub
```